# Huawei HMS - Open app from browser with custom uri schema

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appauth

I'm developing an app that use the AppAuth library.

https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android

In the app I click on a button that open a browser tab with the login page. After the login the website open a custom uri "com.myapp:/oauth2redirect" with data needed to app for the login.

In the devices with Google Chrome (after the login) the app appears, the browser is closed and the user continue to use the app.

In Huawei device with Huawei browser, a snackbar appears asking the user to open the app "The site would like to open APP". This snackbar disappears after 5 seconds. If the user click on the snackbar the browser is closed and the app appears, but if the user don't click it and close the browser the app don't receive the login params and nothing works.

For the users is more complicated because have to do more actions to do a simple operation that on Google devices is automatic.

Someone use AppAuth or custom uri scheme on Huawei devices? How to solve this problem?

Comment: According to our long-term voice from users, the pop-up window that automatically opens the app or downloads the APK which may cause a security risk to users.  that's why a redirection message is added in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please Set device default browser to Chrome using Settings->Apps->Default Apps->Browser App

BTW, Could the app handle redirect URI with the following configuration as suggested by the app developer in [link](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/blob/master/app/README-Google.md)  on HMS phone normally?

[image]

Comment: The device is Huawei with HMS.  Chrome is not installed.

Comment: The app works, but on Huawey the user have to do more step to open the app.
When the browser make a redirect to "redirect_uri" on google chrome the app is opened automaticaly, on huawei appears a snackbar that ask to the user to open the app.
Anyway, I just received a reply from huawey support. 
This more step is needed by chinese law that requires a confirmation before perform a third-party redirection.